# how to use the useEffect hook on component unmount to conditionally run code

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

For some odd reason the value of props in my "unmount" useEffect hook is always at the original state (true), I can console and see in the devtools that it has changed to false but when the useEffect is called on unmount it is always true.
I have tried adding the props to the dependancies but then it is no longer called only on unmount and does not serve it's purpose.
**Edit**: I am aware the dependancy array is empty, I cannot have it triggered on each change, it needs to be triggered ONLY on unmount with the update values from the props. Is this possible?

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (report.data.draft) { // this is ALWAYS true
        report.snapshot.ref.delete();
      }
    };
  }, []);
```

How can I conditionally run my code on unmount with the condition being dependant on the updated props state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want code to run on unmount only, you need to use the empty dependency array. If you also require data from the closure that may change in between when the component first rendered and when it last rendered, you'll need to use a `ref` to make that data available when the unmount happens. For example:

```
const onUnmount = React.useRef();
onUnmount.current = () => {
  if (report.data.draft) {
    report.snapshot.ref.delete();
  }
}
React.useEffect(() => {
  return () => onUnmount.current();
}, []);
```

If you do this often, you may want to extract it into a custom hook:

```
export const useUnmount = (fn): => {
  const fnRef = useRef(fn);
  fnRef.current = fn;

  useEffect(() => () => fnRef.current(), []);
};


// used like:
useUnmount(() => {
  if (report.data.draft) {
    report.snapshot.ref.delete();
  }
});
```

Comment: This worked for me with a slight variation, I could not save a function in the `current` of the ref, this caused it to be triggered on mount as well. I simply put the `report.data.draft` into the `current` of the ref and it works great. Thanks!

Comment: I had a typo in my initial post. For my proposal to work, make sure you do `return () => onUnmount.current();`, not `return onUnmount.current();` like i originally wrote.

Answer (score 2):

The dependency list of your effect is empty which means that react will only create the closure over your outer variables once on mount and the function will only see the values as they have been on mount. To re-create the closure when `report.data.draft` changes you have to add it to the dependency list:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        if (report.data.draft) { // this is ALWAYS true
            report.snapshot.ref.delete();
        }
    };
}, [report.data.draft]);
```

There also is an eslint plugin that warns you about missing dependencies: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks

Comment: Beat me to it. :D

Comment: @trixn If I add it to the dependancy list then it is triggered on each change of that value, I only want it to run when the component unmounts.

Comment: @Michael I see, that usually means that the component does something that is outside of its responsibility. Instead a component higher up the tree that manages the `report` object should do the cleanup when the state change that triggers the unmount happens. It the `report` provided to the component as a prop? You could still make it work by doing what Nicholas Tower proposed in his answer but I feel like this is kind of an anti-pattern.

Comment: @trixin that's an interesting question, the component updates the db which has a subscription on the top level component who then send the data back down. I am fairly new to React (come from Vue) but given that there are a number of components and sending the data all the way to the data fetching component would be complex and this is 2 lines of code, I think it's fine.

Comment: @Michael I see and that is fine. Just wanted to point out that this is probably a side effect that ideally should be handled on a higher level. Enforcing the correct pattern here might indeed turn out to require a little more effort. I just wanted to point out that it could and maybe should be resolved by another layer of abstraction, in that case e.g. the editor component should be controlled by another component that cleans up any draft in response to the same user interaction that also closes the editor component rather than in the cleanup of the useeffect if that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Using custom js events you can emulate unmounting a componentWillUnmount even when having dependency. Here is how I did it.

**Problem:**

```
    useEffect(() => {
    //Dependent Code
    return () => {
        // Desired to perform action on unmount only 'componentWillUnmount' 
        // But it does not
        if(somethingChanged){
            // Perform an Action only if something changed
        }
    }
},[somethingChanged]);
```

**Solution:**

```
// Rewrite this code  to arrange emulate this behaviour

// Decoupling using events
useEffect( () => {
    return () => {
        // Executed only when component unmounts,
        let e = new Event("componentUnmount");
        document.dispatchEvent(e);
    }
}, []);

useEffect( () => {
    function doOnUnmount(){
        if(somethingChanged){
            // Perform an Action only if something changed
        }
    }

    document.addEventListener("componentUnmount",doOnUnmount);
    return () => {
        // This is done whenever value of somethingChanged changes
        document.removeEventListener("componentUnmount",doOnUnmount);
    }

}, [somethingChanged])
```

**Caveats:** *useEffects* have to be in order, *useEffect* with no dependency have to be written before, this is to avoid the event being called after its removed.